# extract all number in 1:1000 which begin first digit==2

Tags: r, substr

*emphasized text*i have a vector data and i want to get all data begin with 2 example

x<-1:1000

i want to get this answer:
"2" , "22" , "222"

Comment: Did you meant only first digit or all digits?

Comment: what have you tried so far to solve this problem yourself ... ?

Comment: This question is not clear enough and needs more detail with what the aim is

Answer (score 3):

If we want to return numbers that are only 2, an option is `grep` to match a pattern of one or more '2' (`2+`) from the start (`^`) of the string till the end (`$`) of the string

```
as.numeric(grep('^2+$', x, value = TRUE))
#[1]   2  22 222
```

or for the first digit alone, just specify the start (`^`) followed by the digit 2

```
as.numeric(grep('^2', x, value = TRUE))
```

Or with `substr`

```
x[substr(x, 1, 1) == 2]
```

#### data

```
x <- 1:1000
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which one is what you are looking for exactly

```
> x[startsWith(as.character(x), "2")]
  [1]   2  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29 200 201 202 203 204 205 206
 [19] 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224
 [37] 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242
 [55] 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260
 [73] 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278
 [91] 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296
[109] 297 298 299
```

or

```
> x[grepl("^2+$", x)]
[1]   2  22 222
```